# Dock does not switch back to primary display

Tags: plank, desktop, display

In a  monitor setup having monitor A as external and monitor B as built-in monitor where monitor A is setup as primary display.

When I unhook my monitor the dock is correctly place on the built-in monitor. Now when I reconnect the laptop to my external monitor A the dock will not revert back to the primary display. You need to change your primary display to built-in, apply it and then do the same process again for your external monitor.

Is there a way to fix this so that the dock is always displayed on the primary monitor?

Thanks

Felix

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with using two docks when connected to external display. I wrote a small script that I have to execute each time I (dis-)connect to external display. I don't know any other solution then to restart plank. Just type in terminal:

`killall plank`

If you did not change any settings in cerbere, plank would instantly restart with default settings ("show on primary") and should appear on the external display (if this one was automatically set as primary display).

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is related to this [long-standing bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1292398), i.e. displays' settings are not preserved from one session to another or after a disconnection.

It says "Fix released" on elementary's side, but I'm not so sure about this. Can any dev confirm this?